# Defining the size of an array during the execution in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memory-management

I would like to know if I can define the size of an array in C, during the execution.
For example, can I do this?

```
int n,i;
scanf("%d",&n);
int v[n];
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
 v[i] = i;
}
```

If this is possible, when should I use the function malloc for dynamic allocation of memory? I mean, if I can read a value n and allocating an array with n positions, during the execution, why should I use malloc?

Comment: You use `malloc` if the storage has to persist after the function returns.  It is also needed if you wish to free storage in an arbitrary order.

Comment: Can you provide more details? I didn't understand.

Comment: A function allocates memory and returns a pointer to it.  You have to use `malloc` for that.  For instance, a function that adds an element to a linked list and then returns.

Comment: You can do this if your compiler supports [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)s.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a variable to specify the length of an array only if the compiler supports Variable-Length Arrays. These were added to the C99 standard, but are now optional under the C11 standard.

Answer (score 2):

One of the  differences is, when you declare an array inside a function, it is allocated on the stack. It is a local to that function, and when the function returns, it is deallocated automatically. malloc, allocates on the heap, and returns a pointer to the starting address of the allocated memory. Unlike the storage on the stack, it is not automatically deallocated, if you return the pointer from the function, you can use it in another function, until you free it. 
This can be useful for more info: http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/data-structures/difference-between-stack-and-heap/